# naming conventions with backbone.js (on rails)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

This is not specifid to backbone but it's how I got to asking myself this question. I'm using the backbone-rails gem to integrate backbone in my rails app. The built-in generators produces objects names likes this : `Appname.Routers.PostsRouter`, `Appname.Views.Posts.EditView`, etc.

I was wondering: is it really necessary to append `Router` or `View` at the end of the object name, since they are namespaced? I don't do JS much, same for backbone, so I'm not sure of the usual conventions, but from where I stand, it seems redundant to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. It's just the way the gem's author chose to name them.